# Writing a program to count the number of recursive calls

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Suppose I have the following recursive function, that returns the nth fibonacci number:

```
private int fib(int n) {
    if(n == 1) return 0;
    if(n == 2) return 1;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

How would I write a piece of code to return the total number of recursive calls made by this function ? I was thinking of introducing a count parameter as in `fib(int n, int count = 0)` or a static variable inside `fib` as `static int count = 0` and increment count right before the recursive call. I had no success with either of these two approaches as I couldn't return `count`. Is there a way to get the total number of recursive calls without modifying the original function ?

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: Just declare the counter outside the fuction and increment it inside the function. That is a badly written algorithm of fibonacci....

Comment: A global variable (outside the function's scope) should do the job.  However, if you can't alter the function, I don't see how you can affect this count variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate by induction that the number of recursion calls to calculate `F(n)` is `2 * F(n) - 1` (for the basic case where `n <= 2` it is 1). Try to write induction steps, if you will not be able, I will update my answer with a proof later.

So actually there is no need to write a recursive algorithm. Also there is `O(log(n))` algorithm to calculate n-th fibonacci number based on matrix exponentiation.

[image]

So with some math, you can end up with an `O(log(n))` algorithm to find the number of recursive calls. But if you will continue modifying your function, you will find this in approximately `O(1.6^n)`

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the function? Use a proxy:

- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-proxies.html#proxy
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html#examples

```
Foo foo = (Foo) DebugProxy.newInstance(new FooImpl());
foo.bar(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reference variable to keep track of the times the function is called.

Why don't you try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 int fib(int n,int& count) {
     count++;
    if(n == 1) return 0;
    if(n == 2) return 1;
    return fib(n - 1,count) + fib(n - 2,count);
}
int main()
{
   int nth=7;
   int count=0;
   int num=fib(nth,count);

   cout<<nth<<"th fibonacci sequence is "<<num<<" function calls: "<<count<<"recursive calls:"<<count-1<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```